# Output folder contents to .CSV with alphabets removed from filename

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, bash

I would like to turn the contents(filenames) of a folder into a .csv

My problem is that the files are organised in sets. I only want to output the filename of each set without anything else but the first numbers.

Desired Output:

### [image: CSV]

Example of files in folder:

- 10405a.jpg
- 10405b.jpg
- 10405c.jpg
- 160405a.jpg
- 160405b.jpg
- 160405c.jpg
- 2002035-1.jpg
- 2002035-2.jpg
- 2002035-3.jpg

---

I found some code that i modified with no luck.
I assume i have to loop through the files and check for any non-digit characters and pars that somehow. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
set src to (choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder where source tree is rooted at")'s POSIX path
    set theCsv to ""
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in src
        tell application "Finder" to set this_item to displayed name of item i of src
        set this_item to this_item & ",\\n"
        set theCsv to theCsv & this_item
    end repeat
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theCsv & " > ~/Desktop/names.csv"
```

Comment: If this is a one time thing I'd just use **Terminal** and `cd` to the _target directory_ and, assuming it contains only the _target files_, use the following _compound command_: `echo 'Object #' > "$HOME/Desktop/names.csv"; ls | grep -Eo '^[0-9]+' | sort -u >> "$HOME/Desktop/names.csv"`

Comment: @ user3439894 Thanks! That works great. I will have to do this on a weekly basis. The directory will only contain these target. Perhaps I can implement this in some sort of AppleScript and run it every week.

Comment: Another thing, this Target Directory is on a local Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set src to quoted form of ¬
    (choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder where source tree is rooted at")'s POSIX path

set shellCommand to ¬
    "cd " & src & " && echo 'Object #' > \"$HOME/Desktop/names.csv\"; ls | grep -Eo '^[0-9]+' | sort -u >> \"$HOME/Desktop/names.csv\""

do shell script shellCommand
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. Modified it a bit and got it to work on my mounted volume.